# How to insert into Bigquery a field that is to recieve json string value?

Tags: google-bigquery

In a Python script, I am trying to insert a record in a bigquery table.  One of the fields is to receive the value of Json object as a string. Here is the code I use to do that:

```
query = "INSERT into config.job_config  ( job_name, run_id, task_name, task_step, run_config, version, run_time) VALUES (" + "'" + self.job_name + "', '" + self.run_id + "', '"+self.task_name + "', '"+ task_step + "', '"+ json.dumps(configy) +"', '" + self.config_version+ "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() "+")"
print query
query_job = self.bq_client.run_sync_query(query)
query_job.timeout_ms = 60000
query_job.run()
```

The following is what "print query" statement generated:

```
INSERT into config.job_config  ( job_name, run_id, task_name, task_step, run_config, version, run_time) VALUES ('copy:temp.test_lines', 'run-id-123', 'BQLoadGcsFile', '1', '{"gcs": {"landing_bucket": "gs://test-development", "landing_dir": "/lineitems/", "archive_bucket": "gs://test-development", "archive_dir": "/archive/"}, "gcs_to_bq_job_id": "test_lines-run-id-123-2017-07-13"}', '3.0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
```

When I execute that insert statement in the UI, it works fine.  However, when the above code executes, it generates the following error:

```
File "/home/fereshteh/utils/scheduler_config.py", line 87, in insert_task_instance_config
query_job.run()
File "/home/fereshteh/google-cloud-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/query.py", line 364, in run
method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
File "/home/fereshteh/google-cloud-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 303, in api_request
error_info=method + ' ' + url)
google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Encountered "" at line 1, column 43.
[Try using standard SQL 
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)] (POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/sansar-dev/queries)
```

when I add "query.use_legacy_sql = False" (from https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html#querying-data-synchronous):

```
query_job = self.bq_client.run_sync_query(query)
query_job.timeout_ms = 60000
query.use_legacy_sql = False
query_job.run()
```

It gives the following error:

```
    query.use_legacy_sql = False     
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'use_legacy_sql'
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query` is your query string rather than the job. It looks like it should be:

```
query_job = self.bq_client.run_sync_query(query)
query_job.timeout_ms = 60000
query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
query_job.run()
```

Comment: Thx. However, my real reason for posting (before diversion by the legacy issue) was how to handle escaped chars when reading and writing back records to BQ.  In the fist insert (which is manual) all chars like single quote (I am using " for string fields) or \ have to be escaped for the insert to work.  But then the script reads the record and the fld containing the json (using json.loads), and then it has to insert back that record into BQ again, and this time the "\" chars used for escaping are all gone (by the json.loads) which causes error when trying to insert the record. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't see your other question earlier. Your best bet is probably to use Python triple-quotes (`"""<query>"""` or use single quotes) or you can load the query from a file so that you don't have to worry about escaping at all.